# Woocommerce/Wordrpess do_shortcode() paginación de productos no funciona correctamente

Tags: php, ajax, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin

Estoy desarrollando un plugin de búsqueda de productos mediante parámetros,esto lo hago por `AJAX`.

Al momento de ejecutarmediante el método `do_shortcode()`  de wordpress  me muestra correctamente todos los productos  pero la paginación no funciona

El enlace de la paginación y la URL que muestra es la siguiente :

```
www.mipagina.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?product-page=2
```

Todas las solicitudes AJAX en wordpress se hacen a esa dirección `admin-ajax.php` pero la direccion que debería tomar el `shortcode` de woocommerce es la de la pagina principal y no la del `AJAX`

La dirección debería ser la siguiente:

```
www.mipagina.com/paginaactual/?product-page=2
```

Codigo:

```html
//la lista de productos la genero mediante un for each 
$listaProductos = "1,2,155,616,4454,123,3223,656565,656,8899,6565,655665,3232,9,5652,26262,888,0001";


if(!$listaProductos == "") {
  echo do_shortcode("[products ids='$listaProductos' per_page='12' columns='3' paginate='true' limit='-1']");
}else{
  echo "No hay productos disponibles.";
}
wp_die();
```

Comment: me parece que el problema debe estar en el constructor de la url... o algo lo esta alterando...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solución temporal :**

De momento la solución fue Quitar el paginado y mostrar un máximo de 30 productos.
Con el siguiente código :

```html
if(!$listaProductos == "") {
  echo do_shortcode("[products ids='$listaProductos' per_page='30' columns='3' ]");
}else{
  echo "No hay productos disponibles.";
}
wp_die();
```

A medida avance el proyecto iré actualizando el estado de esta respuesta  ya que otra de las ideas es modificar el atributo "`href`" de los productos mediante Jquery